# determine if a message was sent or closed outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

in c # I create a message m before sending it I show the user who can edit it and send or close it. How can I track the user closed this message or sent.

```
OutLookRef.Application oApp;
            oApp = new OutLookRef.Application();


            OutLookRef.MailItem mail = oApp.CreateItem(OutLookRef.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            var pInspector = mail.GetInspector;

            mail.Recipients.Add(address);  
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.HTMLBody = body;
            mail.Display();
```

All I got was to pause the code while this window is open

```
while (pInspector.CurrentItem is OutLookRef.MailItem)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            }
```

also after sending, I would like to save this message to a disk, let's say mail.msg

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are interested in the following properties:

- [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) returns an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent.
- [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) returns a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.
- [Namespace.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a `Recipient` object.

> also after sending, I would like to save this message to a disk, let's say mail.msg

You may hook up to the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class which belongs to the `Sent Items` folder where you can save the item on the disk. The [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.